# Are Packages In Centos Yum Repo's Secure?

Tags: security, centos7, yum, package-management, repository

I have tried to do research to figure out this issue, but I would like to hear from the community to understand if what is available in the Yum repo is secure. Even when the versions in the repository in many cases are very old versions of what is available.

RedHat shares in their article -> https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/what-backporting-and-how-does-it-apply-rhel-and-other-red-hat-products that packages in their repos are maintained by RedHat and that they apply important security patches to their versions where they feel that it is appropriate. So that the version of their applications may be old versions, but that they are receiving backports.

Below are the repos that one of our servers is using. We are on Centos 7.9 and install regular updates for kernel and other packages using the following repositories:

---

```
repo id                           repo name                       status
base/7/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - Base                 10,072
epel/x86_64                       EPEL YUM Repo                   13,768
extras/7/x86_64                   CentOS-7 - Extras                  518
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64 MySQL Connectors Community         227
mysql-tools-community/x86_64      MySQL Tools Community              100
mysql57-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.7 Community Server         678
percona-release-noarch/7          Percona Original release/noarch     65
percona-release-x86_64/7          Percona Original release/x86_64  2,628
updates/7/x86_64                  CentOS-7 - Updates               5,287
```

---

My question comes from when packages like firewalld in the yum repo is on version 0.6.3 but the most recent version that is available is version 2.0.0. [Firewalld Versions](https://firewalld.org/download/all.html) . There are backports that have been made to the firewalld package, but the last one was in April 2021. It seems like a long time to not have some kind of security vulnerability update.

I was expecting to see more frequent backports to system packages that address vulnerabilities that apply to the RedHat/Centos repository version.

My internal scans are not stating that there is an issue, but when I see the versions so out of date it makes me wonder if we should be more critical of the packages installed to make sure they are on more up to date versions.

Thank you for your time and comments
James Anderson

Comment: The question "are yum repo's secure" can't be answered. The CentOS repos pretty much have to be trusted. The MySQL and Percona repos are extremely likely able to be trusted. If you start adding other external repos then it is up to your judgement on what is safe.

Comment: You also cannot rely on the major version numbers to determine if a package has been updated. REL backports security updates into the versions existing  at the time of the LTS release. Check the release notes on packages like firewalld to see what patches have been applied.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. @doneal24 - This is the crux of my question and I think its what I want to know how the community feels. My security scans appear to think that the backported versions are safe and secure. But I was feeling a little uneasy being on such an old version and not knowing if scans just don't consider them insecure because of the way that Centos/RH change the version numbers to match their modifications.

In addition to that I have been looking at the backport history using `rpm -qa -changelog <packageName> To see where patches have been applied. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of long term support. Packages are updated, without being upgraded, so third party software is unlikely to break. The price is that backports may take some time, and you can't get the new features.

> It seems like a long time to not have some kind of security vulnerability update.

Why? `firewalld` isn't a firewall. It's a firewall management tool. The firewall is in the kernel (netfilter/iptables). Firewalld merely tells that what to do, so there's not any reasons to expect huge security vulnerabilities in it.

Comment: Good point about firewalld. I guess it was one that caught my eye as not being on the most up-to-date version and had been a while since a backport because while it is not the firewall itself it does control how the firewall configuration is implemented. Which in my mind means that vulnerabilities to the software could lead to vulnerabilities within my firewall implementation. Thank you for responding and sharing your feedback.